# Proxy Reverse Pass getting mixed content warning

Tags: apache, configuration, reverse-proxy, proxypass

Currently We have a `ProxyReversePass` apache site conf that from my understanding ( I was given this project long after the person who worked on it left. There seems to be no documentation on setup other than the ansible roles )
We have another domain specifically to serve the wordpress site while the main one runs on magento. Using a ProxyReversePass we were able to load up the contents of the wordpress site using the domain of the magento site. However recently after a server update ( not sure what caused the issue ) we are seeing mixed content warnings on the live site which is messing up the styling as well as loading stuff from `blog.example.com` instead of just `example.com/blog`

This is my apache Conf:

```
<VirtualHost SERVER_IP:443>
    ServerName example.com 
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/site
    ErrorLog /var/log/site.error.log

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProtocol protocols
    SSLCertificateFile path/to/certs 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile path/to/certs
    SSLCACertificateFile path/to/certs

    ProxyPass /blog http://blog.example.com/blog
    ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.example.com/blog

    <Directory /path/to/site>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```